# How to undo 'List Only' permission for folder?

Tags: permissions

I accidentally set '**List Only**' permission to a very important folder of mine with the intention of hiding it from my employees. But now, even I'm unable to access it. The notification reads out

> "You do not have the permissions necessary to view the contents of
>   'Folder-name'."

I tried to change the permissions but it reads out again:

> "Permissions of 'Folder-name' could not be determined."

How do I undo the 'List Only' permission now? Please help. Its a very important folder for my business.

Comment: You need to see the permissions of the folder: $ ls -ld Folder-name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to give some rights to some users/groups and some other rights to some other users/groups, I  think you can change permnssions you need to change accessing via terminal to the parent directory, then giving a

```
sudo -i
```

and finally

```
chmod [-R] xxx /path/to/your/folder
```

(don't forget to close root shell by `exit` or simply giving the previous command using sudo: 
`sudo chmod [-R] xxx /path/to/your/folder` )

where -R means *recursively*, i.e. it changes permissions as indicated by *xxx*to every file and subdirectory in it and xxx is the set of permissions you want to state.

I've used "xxx" but each "x" stays for "rwx" by powers of 2 (three values for Owner, Group, Others), so rwx,rwx,rwx will be 777 (1*2^2+1*2^1+1*2^0=4+2+1=7, three times) and the "list only" you actually have, r--,r--,r--, will be 444 (1*2^2+0*2^1+0*2^0=4+0+0=4, three times).

Cheers,

Silvia